# How to prevent Up Navigation in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/addstoryselectclassactivity_label", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait,
ParentActivity=typeof(FeedListActivity))]
[MetaData("android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY", Value = "EducaAndroid.FeedListActivity")]
```

After adding ParentActivity flag to activity in xamarin, activity has start showing up navigation on the screen. How can i prevent this ?

Answer (score 0):

After looking couple of class finally i founded disabling up navigation over here

```
ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled (false);
```